# Find first result (QueryDsl, Mongodb)

Tags: mongodb, querydsl, mongorepository

Using MongoDB, we have two way to do requests on our repositories:

1. The queryBy method: `findOneByUsernameAndType...`
2. The Querydsl method which allows us to pass a criteria and retrieve a list of result.

When I do a `findOneBy`, I retrieve the first document corresponding to the request, even if there was a lot of results.

But I have a complicated query so I can't use this method because its name is too long and I can't do what i want.

So i want to do the same with query dsl:

```
foo = repository.findOne(criteria);
```

with criteria a DTO with 3 attribute.

The problem is that if there are more than 1 result, this `findOne` throw an exception instead of returning the first result.

How can I do that with Querydsl?

Comment: Well.. I just found a solution that do the trick:
Page<Foo> results = repository.findAll(criteria, new PageRequest(0, 1));
if(results.iterator().hasNext()){
       foo= results.iterator().next();
}

Answer (score 0):

You want to return more than one value if I do not understand your problem wrongly
The following code blocks will help you

Document: http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/2.1.0/reference/html/ch02s07.html

**JAVA**

```
QMember qMember = new QMember("member");
MongodbQuery<Member> query = new MongodbQuery<Member>(morphia, datastore, qMember);
List<Member> members= query
    .where(qMember.Name.eq("furkaan"))
    .list();
```

**.NET (C#)**

mongodb.driver dll version 2.4

.Find() extention method

namespace: MongoDB.Driver.IMongoCollectionExtensions

```
public static Main(){
    list<Member> members= Filter<Member>(x=>x.Name.Contains("furkaan","member"));
}

public static List<T> Filter<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expressionFunc, string collectionName = null)
{
    //var database = getDatabase()  todo get database
    List<T> results = new List<T>();
    var collection = database.GetCollection<T>(collectionName);
    if (collection != null)
    {
        results = collection.Find(expressionFunc).ToList();
    }
    return results;
}
```